# Multiple Spatial Joins with GeoPandas in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, spatial-join, geopandas

Is it somehow possible to make several spatial joins with GeoPandas without always saving the outcome and loading it again?

I have to join like six different Esri Shapefiles and it takes really long to save them every time.

My code:

```
import geopandas


#first join
grid = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file("inputpath")
dem = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file("inputpath2")
sjoin = geopandas.sjoin(grid, dem, how = "left")
sjoin.to_file("outputpath", driver='ESRI Shapefile')

#second join with outcome of first join
griddem = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file("outputpath")
slope = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file("inputpath3")
sjoin2 = geopandas.sjoin(griddem, slope, how = "left")  
sjoin2.to_file("outputpath2", driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

I already tried to directly use the outcome of the first join for the second join like I did in the following code:

```
import geopandas


#first join
grid = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file("inputpath")
dem = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file("inputpath2")
sjoin = geopandas.sjoin(grid, dem, how = "left")

#second join with outcome of first join
slope = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file("inputpath3")
sjoin2 = geopandas.sjoin(sjoin, slope, how = "left")
```

But I got following error code:

`File "/anaconda2/envs/IP3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/tools/sjoin.py", line 51, in sjoin
    " joined".format(index_left, index_right))
ValueError: 'index_left' and 'index_right' cannot be names in the frames being joined`

Is there any solution to make this work efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geopandas won't let you create duplicate columns for `index_left` and `index_right`. Unless there's a particular reason that you need the original indexes it's simple enough to [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the duplicates between each step, e.g.

```
sjoin.drop('index_left', axis=1, inplace=True)
sjoin.drop('index_right', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Given you have several datasets to join you can even put this in a loop and use the python [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) (note, this in Python 2.7 this you don't need the `functools` import) method to put the joins and subsequent column removals in a loop:

```
from functools import reduce  # python 3 only

import geopandas as gpd

def join_reducer(left, right):
    """
    Take two geodataframes, do a spatial join, and return without the
    index_left and index_right columns.
    """
    sjoin = gpd.sjoin(left, right, how='left')
    for column in ['index_left', 'index_right']:
        try:
            sjoin.drop(column, axis=1, inplace=True)
        except ValueError:
            # ignore if there are no index columns
            pass
    return sjoin

input_frames = [
    gpd.read_file(path) for 
    for path in ['inputpath1', 'inputpath2', 'inputpath3', ...]
]
sjoin = reduce(join_reducer, input_frames)
sjoin.to_file('outputpath')
```

Comment: Worked Perfect! Do you also know how it is possible that the output shp file is about 350mb and the dbf file about 800mb in size, seems too huge? The 7 join input shp files are just between 1 and 20 mb big?